# Load testing services for mqtt

Tags: service, mqtt, load-testing

We need to make a full stack load testing. And the data journey is starting from mqtt client. Are there any good services to make a load testing for such case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the number of virtual users you would like to simulate and your budget the options are in:

- [CloudMQTT](https://www.cloudmqtt.com) service which is free for 5 connections and 10 Kbit/s bandwidth
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a free and open source multi-protocol load testing tool. Out of the box JMeter does not support MQTT protocol however there are plugins like:

  - [mqtt-jmeter](https://github.com/emqtt/mqtt-jmeter)
  - [MQTT plugin](https://github.com/tuanhiep/mqtt-jmeter)

  Check out [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide)
- [MQTT-Stresser](https://github.com/inovex/mqtt-stresser)
- [MQTT Toolbox](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-toolbox-mqttbox/)

So feel free to choose one of the above (or other solution), the final choice mostly depends on your project infrastructure and possibility of i of test tool ntegration into your product delivery lifecycle

Comment: Unfortunately all those are not services but just tools. And I don't want tools. I want a complete service for that.

Comment: https://github.com/krylovsk/mqtt-benchmark , i found this tool very good , its written in golang